# What settings in cv2.threshold() to threshold this image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-thresholding

I would like to convert this image to gray scale in OpenCV and then find the settings to threshold it. I want to threshold the black spaces inside of the skull. Can someone write out a Python script using OpenCV?

I convert to grayscale with: gray = `cv2.cvtColor(pic, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

When I do `(ret, thresh) = cv2.threshold(gray, 177, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)` I get a black image.

When I do `(ret, thresh) = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)` the whole head becomes a white blob.

[image]

Comment: Read [this](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html). You might want to give [Otsu's Threshold](https://learnopencv.com/otsu-thresholding-with-opencv/) a try.

Comment: Try experimenting with a slider, you can find the optimal result faster that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i has understood your goal correctly, here is my proposal. It uses Otsu's Thresholding as @stateMachine has said.

```
import cv2

im = cv2.imread("IScDg.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Your first method
(_, thresh1) = cv2.threshold(gray, 177, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Your second method
(ret, thresh2) = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Proposed method
(_, thresh3) = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 1, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

[different thresholds on your image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVXge.png)

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Can you explain why you wrote "(_, thresh3)"? Question 1: Why an underscore instead of the usual "ret"? Question 2: Why put parenthesis around these two variables?

Comment: Hi @DaveNguyen. I put the underscore because the variable `ret` is not going to be used. I did not realize that I kept the `ret` variable in the second method but it is not used either. The parenthesis are used because the function `cv2.threshold()` returns a tuple, but without them it works fine too.

Answer (score 0):

I usually apply OTSU with good results.

```py
ret,gray = cv2.threshold(gray,100,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

Comment: For some reason, this line didn't work for me. Thanks, though